# Preprocessor test for equality always evaluates true

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Using this:

```
-DME=AWESOME
```

and this:

```
#if ME==AWESOME

#error Im awesome!

#endif
```

yields this:

> Registers.cpp:59:2: error: #error Im awesome!

but this:

```
#if ME==NOTSOGREAT

#error Im confused!

#endif
```

yields this:

> Registers.cpp:59:2: error: #error Im confused!

Comment: The C preprocessor only handles numeric, not string, data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that doing `-DME=AWESOME` is equivalent to your source file starting with:

```
#define ME AWESOME
```

Now let's look at `#if ME==AWESOME`.  Token replacement changes `ME` to `AWESOME`, so the final version of this line is:

```
#if AWESOME==AWESOME
```

When you use `==` in the preprocessor, an alphabetic token that is not `#define`d to anything else, gets replaced by `0`. So this tests `#if 0 == 0` which is true, so your error is displayed.

Now, looking at:

```
#if ME==NOTSOGREAT
```

After token replacement it is:

```
#if AWESOME==NOTSOGREAT
```

which again is equivalent to `#if 0 == 0`, which is true.

---

If you also had `#define AWESOME 5` before this, then you would find that the first test is true but the second test is false.

I guess you are trying to detect if `ME` had been defined to `AWESOME` but there is no way to do that; you can only test whether `ME` has been defined as something equal to whatever `AWESOME` has been defined as.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I see this done in vendor supplied code: #if (CPU == ARMARCH7M) after it is defined in the makefile: CPU = SIMPENTIUM

Comment: @user1229731 You will find that `ARMARCH7M` and `SIMPENTIUM` are defined as (probably non-zero) numeric values somewhere, probably by a header file included before this `#if`

Comment: That also makes sense.  However, whenever I test for CPU == ARMARCH7M or CPU == SIMPENTIUM, it always evaluates true.

Comment: @uesr1229731 make sure you have included the header file defining those things. You can check by doing `#ifdef ARMARCH7M` to see if that symbol is defined, and so on.  If you're still having trouble you could try writing `int t[] = { CPU, ARMARCH7M, SIMPENTIUM };` and then inspecting the preprocessor output, if your compiler supports that. (with gcc it is `gcc -E`)

Comment: I will look deeper into the vendor's code.  I don't want to be redundant, and I don't like this either, but for now I will do this:      #if defined(_CPU_ARMARCH7)
    ...
    #elif defined(_CPU_SIMPENTIUM)
    ...

Comment: Probably worth investigating further; if the vendor code does contain `if CPU == ARMARCH7M`, and if the `ARMARCH7M` define is not correctly defined, then the vendor headers might be malfunctioning which could lead to problems